# Set text from activity1 to activity2

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

i want to have the same text entered in editText1(Activity1) to editText2(Activity2)

In Activity1:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all1);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("editTextentered", editText1.getText().toString()); 
                startActivity(intent);  
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

In Activity2:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    private EditText editText1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        String editTextentered = null;

        if(extras !=null && extras.containsKey("editTextentered")) {
            editTextVal= extras.getString("editTextentered");
        }
        editText1.setText(""+editTextentered);
    }
}
```

I am trying to debug the application but it crashes
I want to setText in an editText(EditText2) which is entered to the fist editText(EditText1) so as to understand and parse it to double if its needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity 1 you are initializing views outside `onCreate`. you will get `NUllPointerException`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.all1);
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Also in activity 2

```
setContentView(R.layout.settings); // must come first
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
if(extras !=null )
{
   String editTextVal= extras.getString("editTextentered");
   editText1.setText(editTextVal);

 }
```

You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. So you need to set the content to the activity first and then initialize your views.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch these two lines around

```
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
setContentView(R.layout.settings);
```

Your `Views` will return `null` until you have inflated your `layout` as you do with `setContentView()`. So your `onCreate()` should look more like

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.settings);  // this needs to be called before instantiating any Views
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Also, you need to actually get the value of the the `extra` you passed in `Activity2` which you never do so it will be `null`. Change this

```
String editTextentered = null;
```

to

```
String editTextentered = extras.getStringExtra("editTextentered");
```

When your app crashes there is always a reason shown in the logcat. You should use that to help you debug and if you can't figure it out then please post it with your questions on here so it is easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

you will get crash with Null pointer expetion as you are getting id of edit text before setting your lay out 
change your code with the following and run it will work 
in your activity 1 do the following

```
  public class Activity1 extends Activity {


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all1);
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);



    }
```

and in your second activity do the following

```
  public class Activity2 extends Activity {

private EditText editText1; 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.settings);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String editTextentered = null;
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
if(extras !=null && extras.containsKey("editTextentered"))
{
   editTextVal= extras.getString("editTextentered");

}
editText1.setText(""+editTextentered);
}

}
```

Comment: @noobProgrammer glad to help always remember you can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

Activity1.java

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("editTextentered", editText1.getText().toString()); 
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Activity2.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String edittextValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("editTextentered");
    editText1.setText(""+edittextValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never give a value to your variable editTextentered in your second activity. Replace the line `editTextVal= extras.getString("editTextentered");` by `editTextentered= extras.getString("editTextentered");` and then add the following code around the line `editText1.setText(""+editTextentered);` :

```
if(editTextentered != null) {
    editText1.setText(""+editTextentered);
}
```